# How to covert bnf to ebnf from that !? bnf <Z> ::= DCd | D<N>C

Tags: syntax, grammar, bnf, ebnf, computer-science-theory

How to covert bnf to ebnf from that !?

BNF

```
 <Z> ::= DCd | D<N>C 

EBNF

<Z> ::= D[<N>}C[d]

or
 
<Z> ::= D[<N>C[d]]
```

(i think that what wrong in grammar?)

Comment: It's fine as it is. No simplification is possible.

Comment: EBNF is Extended BNF, and typically includes BNF as a subset. That is, if you have something written in BNF, it would typically qualify as EBNF too. So you don't need to do anything to "convert" BNF to EBNF. Instead, your question seems to be more about factoring productions.